# Google Sheet – Extract multiple emails from a cell based on a condition

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm am trying to extract a series of email from a cell based on a condition.

In practice I have a cell with text that looks like this:

```
emailAddress: {u'name': u'STAFF', u'address': u'STAFF@domain.ORG'}
status: {u'response': u'none', u'time': u'1601-01-01T00:00:00Z'}
type: required

emailAddress: {u'name': u'First1 Last1', u'address': u'first1.last1@domain.org'}
status: {u'response': u'accepted', u'time': u'2019-07-31T14:55:01.9766714Z'}
type: optional

emailAddress: {u'name': u'First3 Last3', u'address': first3.last3@d.org'}
status: {u'response': u'accepted', u'time': u'2019-07-31T14:57:47.766Z'}
type: optional
```

Ultimately I would like to have, in a single cell separated by a coma, all the email addresses of the people who accepted the calendar invitation (i.e. u'response':u'accepted')

I managed to do it in a few steps:

1. `=SPLIT(A2,"emailAddress",FALSE,TRUE)` => this divides the text above in 3 cells
2. `=IF(REGEXMATCH(B2,"accepted"),REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}"),"")` => this extracts the email address if the cell contains the word 'accepted'
3. `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B3:Z3)` => this concatenates all the email addresses in a single cell

I would like to do all of that in a single cell but I am not sure how. The obvious solution would be to apply the second step to a range instead of a specific cell, but I couldn't figure out how. Thanks a lot for your help!

Here is a sheet with the input cell, as well as the formulas I used: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yi-FYmTIBoDyPrU1SbtdbtNMWizyR9cKTgJr9CuabxM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem, which turns out to be simpler than expected. All I had to do is to merge all 3 formulas into 1, and englobe it all under the 'arrayformula'. In practice it looks like that:

`ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(D2,"emailAddress",FALSE,TRUE),"accepted"),Regexextract(SPLIT(D2,"emailAddress",FALSE,TRUE),"[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}"),"")))`